# How to use @ExceptionHandler with Spring Interceptor for two JSP pages?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, exception, interceptor

I am working on Spring MVC controller project. I am trying to add security on two jsp pages. Meaning I will intercept the IP Address coming from the request and see whether that IP Address is a valid IP Address or not. If it is not Valid IP Address, then show an error jsp page.

As I am adding this security on two JSP page. So I would like to show different error messages for above two jsp call for invalid IP Address call.

As soon as I hit below url on the browser, it will show my `testOperation` and `testProcess` JSP page if it's a valid ip address call -

```
http://localhost:8080/testweb/testOperation
http://localhost:8080/testweb/testProcess
```

So I implemented the Interceptor for this and then configured Spring MVC Interceptors in the XML as well. Now I am checking for valid ip address case with the below code.

```
@Component
public class IpCheckingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println(requestURI);

        String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
        if (ipAddress == null) {  
            ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
        }
        if (!isValid(ipAddress) && requestURI.equalsIgnoreCase("/testweb/testOperation")) {
            // need to show a proper error message on the jsp

            return false;
        } else if (!isValid(ipAddress) && requestURI.equalsIgnoreCase("/testweb/testProcess")) {
            // need to show a below JSON response as an error on the browser
            // {"response":"You are not authorized to make a call.","error":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","status":"ERROR"}

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

In my context.xml file -

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.testing.interceptor.IpCheckingInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Is this possible to do anyhow? Now as I mentioned above, I need to show different error jsp messages for invalid ip address call depending on which page was called. What is the best way to do this?

I don't want to redirect to other JSP page if possible at all. I want to be on the same page and then show the error message appropriately if possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think if were to do this I would probably be using Spring Security anyway, so I'd try and hook into that. If you don't want to bring in Spring Security for just this tiny use case I'd understand that too.

With the `HandlerInterceptor` you can use `request.getRequestDispatcher(path)` to handle the response. If I were you I would dispatch to a Spring MVC endpoint so that the `DispatcherServlet` handles the content negotiation and view resolution for me (so the `path` in the dispatcher would be mapped to a `@Controller` or `@RestController`).  I might also be tempted to use an AOP interceptor instead of a `HanderInterceptor`, but there might be reasons not to do that which would only become clear once I tried it.

BTW I think you can normally expect that the `request.getRemoteAddr()` points to the `X-Forwarded-For` value if you set up the server correctly (e.g. in Tomcat there is a `RemoteIpValve` that does it). Or you could extract that logic into a `Filter` if you don't control the container.